# Question of calculus concepts

Tags: calculus, functions, monotone-functions

Today I learned some concepts of increasing and decreasing functions, but some is so vague, so I have many questions. Here I can have a list of questions:

1. Functions f(x) is decreasing on an interval (a,b) then f'(x)<0 on (a,b) yes? But what if f'(x)<0. Is a function f(x)decreasing if $f'(x)<0$ on an interval (a,b)
2. Functions f(x)>f(b) in the interval (a,b). so is f decreasing on (a,b).
3. Monotonic functions are flat. If it is a random function f(x), if f(a)=f(b), then is f(x) monotonic on the interval (a,b)?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Monotonic functions are increasing or decreasing

Comment: Decreasing does not imply $f’(x)<0$. For example, consider the function $f(x)=-x^3$ at the point $(0,0)$. $f’(0) = 0, $ however the function is strictly increasing, even at $x=0$. However the converse is true: $f’(x) < 0 \implies$ strictly decreasing.

Comment: @AdamRubinson:  how does $f(x)=x^3$ at $(0,0)$ show decreasing does not imply $f'(x)<0$?

Comment: I meant $-x^3$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson:  you also meant strictly *de*creasing?

Comment: yes but I can’t edit it now. Also a constant function would do the trick too.

Comment: Wow, alot of comments, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Decreasing does not imply $f’(x)<0$. For example, consider the function $f(x)=-x^3$ at the point $(0,0)$. $f’(0) = 0, $ however the function is strictly decreasing, even at $x=0$. Also constant functions like $f(x)= 4$ are decreasing...However the converse is true: $f’(x) < 0 \implies$ strictly decreasing.
2. No. Consider $\sin x$ on $[\frac\pi6,\pi]$
3. Monotonic functions are not necessarily constant functions. But if $f(a)=f(b)$ and $f$ is monotonic on $[a,b]$ then this forces $f$ to be constant. However, I think you could do with clarification. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3907156/29156

Answer (score 0):

1. If a function is *decreasing* it means its *slope* is negative, i.e., $f^\prime (x) < 0$.
2. No.  $f(x) > f(b)$ does not mean that $f(x)$ is decreasing.  It could go up and down (so long as it is always greater than $f(b)$.
3. No.  Monotonic means that the function is either *always increasing* or *always decreasing*.

Comment: 1.  Isn't that what OP said?  2.  Who said anything about $g$?